# Error while using ROSMAKE

Tags: ros, gps-umd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_FUERTE
UBUNTU 10.04

I have followed these instructions.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/gpsd_client/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20gpsd_client

I have installed the gps_umd package and the ros_package_path is also set properly as just roscd gps_umd takes me to the directory.

when I typed
sudo rosmake --rosdep-install

results in

sudo: rosmake: command not found

and when I type

rosmake gpsd_client

results in

```
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  Segmentation fault
```

Please let me know how I can use this stack for my project.

Thanks,
Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41237/error-while-using-rosmake/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-13**:
Please edit your post and provide the following information: which ros distro are you using, which ubuntu version and what's the output `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just restarted the system and typed

roscd gpsd_client

and

rosmake gpsd_client

it WORKED !!!

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-13**:
You had probably forgotten to source the `setup.bash` script, but remembered to include it in your bash profile.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-08-15**:
Yes. Thats what i did.